# Cómo puedo enviar 2 funciones con un solo botón

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

tengo un formulario de laravel que inserta datos a una base de datos, pero tenemos otro más escondido que hace la función de enviar un correo, el primer formulario de registro en base de datos hace la función por la base de datos y el envío de correo por el método post, cuando queremos insertar el código en el Javascript solo nos ejecuta la segunda función siempre, es decir, solo envía el correo, más no inserta a la base de datos, aquí les dejo un código que estoy manejando

```
    <div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Menu</button>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2>Agregar entrega</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form action="{{url('agregar-entrega')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="envio">

                {{csrf_field()}}
                

                <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" name="createdBy"/>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputEditDescripcion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Servicio entregado<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea id="descripcion" class="editor" required name="descripcion" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddEvento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Servicio<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select id="inputAddEvento1" required name="inputAddEvento1" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected>Selecciona un servicio entregado</option>
                      @foreach($todosTalleres as $talleres)
                      <option value="{{$talleres->workshop_id}}" required>{{ $talleres->nombreTodosCurso }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddEvento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Entregado por<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select id="id_partner" required data-old="{{ old('id_partner') }}" name="entregadoPor" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(event)">
                      
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddEvento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Entregado a<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select id="inputAddEvento2" required name="inputAddEvento2" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected>Selecciona un partner</option>
                      @foreach($partners as $partner)
                      <option value="{{$partner->partner_id}}" required>{{ $partner->nombrePartner }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddEvento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Revisado por<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select id="partner" required data-old="{{ old('partner_id') }}" name="revisadoPor" class="form-control" onchange="myFunctionEntregadoPor(event)">
                      
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
           


                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddModalidad" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Modalidad<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="modo" required class="form-control" id="inputAddModalidad">
                      <option selected value="">Selecciona una modalidad</option>
                      <option value="PRESENCIAL">PRESENCIAL</option>
                      <option value="LIVE STREAMING">LIVE STREAMING</option>                    
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, selecciona una modalidad.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
     
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="initAdd-date-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fecha de inicio<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="fechainicial" required type="date" id="initAdd-date-input">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe una fecha de inicio.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="finAdd-date-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fecha de finalización<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="fechafinal" required type="date" id="finAdd-date-input">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe una fecha de fin.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


                 <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"><b>Ubicación</b></label>
                </div>
    

                <div style="" class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddCalle" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Calle<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="street" required placeholder="Calle" name="calle" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddCalle">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe una calle.
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div style="" class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddCiudad" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Ciudad<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="city" required placeholder="Ciudad" name="ciudad" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddCiudad">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe una ciudad.
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div style="" class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddEstado" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estado</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="state"  placeholder="Estado" name="estado" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe un estado.
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div style="" class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddPais" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">País<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="country" required placeholder="País" name="pais" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe un país.
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div style="" class="form-group row">
                  <label for="inputAddUrl" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Url de la ubicación<b style="color: red;">*</b></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="url" required placeholder="Url de la ubicación" name="url" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Por favor, escribe una url de la ubicación.
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox"> <b style="color: #black;">Enviar correo </b></label><br>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="myText" >
                <br>
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="myText1" >
               

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a href="{{url('mis-entregas')}}" style="color: white;" class="m-2 btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
                
                  
                </div>


              </form>


              <form  action="{{asset('contacto/enviar.php')}}" method="post"   id="envio2" >
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="span66">
                            <div class="field your-name form-group" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
                              <input style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background: #ffff" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" data-rule="minlen:4"/>
                              <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field your-email form-group" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
                              <input style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt" type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" id="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" data-rule="email" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Completa este campo')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
                              <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="field subject form-group" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
                              <input  style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background: #ffff" type="text" class="form-control" name="tel"  id="subject" placeholder="Número de WhatsApp" data-rule="minlen:4"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Completa este campo')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
                                            
                              <input type="hidden" name="nombretaller" value="texto">
                              <input type="hidden" name="mensajeResena" value="resena">
                              <input type="hidden" name="asunto" value="Mensaje de ficha tecnica">
                              <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field subject form-group" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
                              <textarea id="textarea" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt" class="form-control" name="mensaje" rows="6" data-rule="required" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Completa este campo')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" ></textarea>
                              <div class="validation"></div>
                            </div>

                          </div>

                        </div>
                        

                        <div class="spancheck" >
                          <input id="terms" type="checkbox" required="" name="terms" value="1" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Selecciona esta casilla para continuar')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/><span style="color: white;"> He leído y aceptado los términos descritos en la <a href="{{ asset('pdf/aviso_de_privacidad.pdf') }}" alt="aviso de privacidad"   target="_blank" style="color: white;">Política de Privacidad.</a> Y autorizo el envío de comunicaciones informativas relativas a las actividades o servicios.</span>
                          <div class="validation"></div><br>   
                     
                          <button type="submit" onclick="submitForms(clickedElement),submitForms2(event)">Place Order</button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              </form>
<button id="submit">hola</button>
```

Y en este otro código es el script para hacer que el botón accione 2 diferentes acciones valga la redundancia

```
submitForms = function(clickedElement){
    document.getElementById("envio").submit();

}
submitForms2 = function(clickEvent){
    document.getElementById("envio2").submit();

}

Y este es el código del envío de correo:


else if($mensajeCorreoResena == "resena"){


$destino= "correo@loquesea.lat";
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$kanbanize= "correo@loquesea.lat";
$cabecera  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabecera .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" . "Cc:" . $kanbanize . "\r\n" . "From: " . $destino ;
$contenido = '
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body> 
hola
</body>
</html>
';
$contenido=utf8_decode($contenido);
$resultado=mail($destino, $asunto, $contenido, $cabecera);

if($resultado){
echo "<script>Swal.fire(
  '-Mensaje enviado',
  'Gracias por contactarnos.-',
  'success'
);window.location.assign('https://mirutadeexito')</script>";
    }
```

No sé si tenga que ver el hecho de que redirecciono de diferente manera, ya que en la insersión de base de datos regreso a una tabla como consulta y en el envío de correo redirecciono a la página principal

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás trabajando con Laravel?, lo digo por que yo ahi veo un PHP plano

Comment: Pienso igual que @BetaM  Aparte de eso: ¿usas algo como PHPMail para mandar los correos? ¿Compruebas que los datos sean correctos antes de mandar los datos a la DB y de mandar el mail?

Comment: Si, de hecho las funciones por separado funcionan, pero al momento de juntar ambos formularios dejan de funcionar y con respecto a laravel, si, es php plano, porque el detalle está en la vista, no formulé la pregunta bien

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo así:

`<button onclick="myFunction1();myFunction2()">Clic aquí</button>`

También puedes usar una función intermedia:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Clic aquí</button>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
         myFunction1();
         myFunction2();
    }
</script>
```

Tambien puedes usar un observador:

`button.addEventListener("click", myFunction1();myFunction2());`

Pero yo no usaría este sistema, crearía un script que comprobase que se han introducido los datos en la DB y después mando el correo y en el caso de que no se mandase el correo, pues que te genere un log o algo y que borre los datos de la DB u otras formulas de hacerlo. Pero no hacer checks es todo un riesgo